# How to pase large amount of data with out ANR in android?

Tags: android, json

My Json service has 2700 records,I want to show these records in my application.
When I parse the data it takes 8min to parse. So my application become non responsive.

How to parse the data in segments wise?

Please suggest me the best way.

Regards,
Sravanya

Comment: Do the work in a background thread.

Comment: Use an AsyncTask.  There are tons of examples of running operations OFF the UI thread.

Comment: You obviously have a design problem : fetching 2700 records over the internet is terrible for data usage and battery life, showing 2700 records to the user is a UX nightmare. personne3000 suggests to fetch only what you need when you need it, and I'd follow that advice if I were you, clearly 2.7k records is not what you need to show on a mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

An [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) would be adapted for this kind of long computations. 8min. is not an acceptable duration for an AsyncTask, since the user/Android system is very likely to kill your application before it is done processing. Hence the use of an external service.

But you are definitely doing something wrong here: fetching 2700 records is not a good idea (too much network usage) and parsing them isn't either if it takes this much time (too much battery usage). You have to limit what you are fetching to only the data you need, and maybe use several requests to fetch just what you need when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) this will let you process the data using a separate thread to the main UI. When processing has finished you can fire a broadcast listener or use onPostExecute to update the UI with the results.

8 mins is a long time though, consider if possible reducing the size of the data requested.

Comment: No, an AsyncTask is probably not the right choice for an 8 minute operation, unless it is given its own executor to not block others.